# User variable not incrementing

Tags: mysql, user-variables

Why would the following query not increment seq?

```
    SELECT   @sq :=if(@previous=uid,@sq,0)+1 as seq
            ,@previous:=uid as user
    FROM test
```

Result:

```
seq    user
1      111
1      111
1      111
1      222
1      222
1      222
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to do `set @sq:=0,@previous:=0` at the front?

Alternatively you can always join it in to the query:

```
SELECT   @sq :=if(@previous=uid,@sq,0)+1 as seq
        ,@previous:=uid as user
FROM test, (select @sq:=0, @previous:=0) foo
```